# Whats the relation between ContentProvider and AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-widget, android-contentprovider, appwidgetprovider

I am trying to learn list widget with the WeatherListWidget example by Google.
Every other place I looked to find info on widget, they used AppWidgetProvider, but
in this example they use ContentProvider.
I checked to see maybe one inherets the other, so it will make sense, but they don't.
I see in the manifest that ContentProvider uses the  tag and AppWidgetProvider uses  tag, because they inherit from different things.

So if you could just try and help me understand what makes a widget a widget. So doesn't a widget need a class that extends AppWidgetProvider?

Hope I was clear in my question... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not related at all. Both are called "Providers" but they provide different things.

App widgets are always implemented by a class which extends `AppWidgetProvider`. Read about this class [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider).

Content providers do something completely different. Quoting from the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html):

> Content providers manage access to a structured set of data.

The [WeatherListWidget](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/WeatherListWidget/index.html) example uses both, but each does something different: The `WeatherDataProvider` is a `ContentProvider` which provides the weather data, and the `WeatherWidgetProvider` is an `AppWidgetProvider` which defines the widget itself:

[image]

Comment: ha ha... found it... i dont approve of the costume to put more then one class in a file... :) i missed the class that extend appwidgetprovider... you have been a greate help. still need to understand what they all do and how, but at list that question has been answered! thanks!

Comment: With time, you will understand. For now it's great that your problem is gone.